# Replacing ">>" in javascript would not work

Tags: javascript

I try to replace ">>" with "hello". It would not work. Why? Any hint appeciated. Thanks.

```
<p id="demo">a string with >> in it.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Replace ">>" with "hello"</button>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
        var res = str.replace(">>", "hello");
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characters are encoded if you read them via .innerHtml.

[image]

Comment: Actually, they are encoded when you read them via `.innerHTML`, which is what you are showing.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting HTML entities, use `.textContent` instead.

`.innerHTML` returns the string parsed by the browser, so, for example, this letter `á` will be converted to `&aacute;`.  Because of that, you're getting `&gt;&gt;` using `innerHTML`.

```html
<p id="demo">a string with >> in it.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Replace ">>" with "hello"</button>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        console.log(document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML); // just to illustrate!
        var str = document.getElementById("demo").textContent; 
        var res = str.replace(">>", "hello");
        document.getElementById("demo").textContent = res;
    }
</script>
```

## Aside note

- The next time in your development, use the function `addEventListener` to bind the events to your elements.
- Try to void the repeated lookup of elements, so you must store this `document.getElementById("demo")` into a variable to avoid repeated search in the current DOM.*

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  var demoElement = document.getElementById("demo");
  console.log(demoElement.innerHTML); // just to illustrate!

  var str = demoElement.textContent;
  var res = str.replace(">>", "hello");
  demoElement.textContent = res;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo">a string with >> in it.</p>
<button>Replace ">>" with "hello"</button>
```

## Resources

- [`Element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

  > The Element property `innerHTML` property is used to get or set a string representing serialized HTML describing the element's descendants.
- [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

  > The `Node.textContent` property represents the text content of a node and its descendants.
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are getting and setting **[`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)**, which parses the string as HTML. And, of course, `>` has a special meaning in HTML.

Instead, use **[`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)**, which treats the string as raw text with no parsing done to it.

```js
function myFunction() {
        var str = document.getElementById("demo").textContent; 
        var res = str.replace(">>", "hello");
        document.getElementById("demo").textContent = res;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo">a string with >> in it.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Replace ">>" with "hello"</button>
```

When the HTML parser looks at a string as HTML and finds valid HTML in the string, it parses it correctly as HTML, but if it finds stray `<` and `>` that don't make valid HTML, it escapes them into **[HTML entities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity)** of `&lt;` and `&gt;`, which you can see here:

```js
// With .innerHTML:

  // Valid HTML in the string returns the string and the HTML
  console.log(document.querySelector("div").innerHTML);

  // HTML syntax, but not valid HTML, returns HTML entities
  console.log(document.querySelector("p").innerHTML);


// With .textContent:

  // Valid HTML is not returned - only the text
  console.log(document.querySelector("div").textContent);

  // HTML Syntax, but not valid HTML, returns unaltered string
  console.log(document.querySelector("p").textContent);
```

```css
h1 { font-size:1.1em; }
```

```html
<h1>Both of the following will have .innerHTML used on them: </h1>
<div>A string with <span>valid HTML</span> in it.</div>
<p>A string with  >>> HTML syntax <<<, but not valid HTML in it.</p>
```